# Activity Scaling Animation shows Black Background

Tags: android, animation, background

I am using this animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toXScale="0.9"
    android:toYScale="0.95" />
```

And then using the code:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_animation_right_to_left, R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in);
```

When the activity is scaled to 0.95, a black background appears behind the activity.

Solution 1 Failed: setting the windowBackground for the Application to another color.
Solution 2 Failed: using this code in the activity:

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.texture_background);
```

Answer (score 0):

add following code to `onCreate()` method after `setContentView()`

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

**update**

Indicates that the display has a secure video output and supports compositing secure surfaces.

If this flag is set then the display device has a secure video output and is capable of showing secure surfaces. It may also be capable of showing protected buffers.

If this flag is not set then the display device may not have a secure video output; the user may see a blank region on the screen instead of the contents of secure surfaces or protected buffers.

Secure surfaces are used to prevent content rendered into those surfaces by applications from appearing in screenshots or from being viewed on non-secure displays. Protected buffers are used by secure video decoders for a similar purpose.

An application creates a window with a secure surface by specifying the FLAG_SECURE window flag. Likewise, an application creates a SurfaceView with a secure surface by calling setSecure(boolean) before attaching the secure view to its containing window.

An application can use the absence of this flag as a hint that it should not create secure surfaces or protected buffers on this display because the content may not be visible. For example, if the flag is not set then the application may choose not to show content on this display, show an informative error message, select an alternate content stream or adopt a different strategy for decoding content that does not rely on secure surfaces or protected buffers.

Comment: It works for one time only!? Then, it's never repeated a returned back to black color. Update: well, as I mentioned, it happened only once. Also, I don't want to prevent the user from taking screenshots.

Comment: try to remove flag at `onResume` method.

Comment: don't use `setFlags` for remove flag. use `clearFlags`:
`getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)`

Comment: Still, not working. However, "sometimes" as I return to this activity, this background appears until the activity is reloaded.